# How to reopen a viewpart from menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

i have one perspective and one viewpart. The viewpart is shown as soon as the program opens.
The viewpart should be the only one and should be closeable.

I have two problems with that behaviour:

1. I want the perspective to be
       shown empty, just a background image
       should being shown.  (How do I do that?)
2. I want to open the
       viewpart from the menu, using the
       command style menu.

So far I can close my viewpart and the perspective is empty.

but

I can not call it from the menu with my selfdefined command.
The code is like

```
public class CallMyViewPart extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell();
        IWorkbenchPage page = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage();

        MyViewPart myViewPart = new MyViewPart();

    return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: It is absolutely possible, I have done that but don't remember the specifics, long time back. It was something like show() and setfocus(). However, in my case the view was configured in the plugin.xml as well. Just commented to tell you that it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was easier than I thought.

```
public class CallMyViewPart extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {      

    @Override      
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {      
        Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell();      
        IWorkbenchPage page = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage();
        try {
        page.showView("somedomain.mainViewpart");
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;      
    }      
}
```